# Absolute urls vs normal one on speed

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I  want to use absolute urls because I  create my project on mvc pattern and
for maintain purpose I wrote something like this on images:
`define(Base_url,www.domain.com);echo Base_url."image url or scrupt url"`;

I want to learn this are in better way? is it fast to write absolute url? I want to achieve max speed on website

Comment: in case of relative path browser will add the hostname to image source path anyway

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's going to hit performance issue but illumine a correct path. Since common MVC frameworks I knew would likely separate their public file such assets you mentioned. They are likely going to confuse you in order to fetch the assets according to its prettify-URL's rule. Then comes a const define or any global static method/function to help you grab the correct URL. To help you also to avoid simple mistake like this (notice the `/`)

```
<img src="images/image.jpg">
<img src="/images/image.jpg">
```

You can always cache it too if you still worry of it existance, since it's static -- surely applicable.

So, if you already get the correct URL/path each time you're going to display your assets without constant `Base_url`, then just don't write it down.

If you aware of performance, it's better to use `const` language construct, as it is [defined in compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3193704/5816907). Or if you're using APC, you can also define it with [`apc_define_constants`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-define-constants.php) to perform built in opcode caching by APC.

Comment: My question is actually different,I want to learn which one is more better for speed Absolute urls or normal?Ok I actualy doesnt use mvc framework I use my own and   I collect my images on public folder as you mentioned,Are there way that is more better write that kind of urls on images?You said cache but I want to get first time image load speed.For example www.mydomain/public/images vs /images? which one is better?Are there way dont write const Base_URL?

Comment: The latter reason i explained should be expanded, but yeah.. hate my grammar. I should mention it before on why don't I explain your expected answer, because you (should) already knew it. Existence vs Non-existence. Who wins? Running a marathon vs sleeping. Which more energy consuming? Adding a single char of var will ofc gain cost for compiling. Furthermore, it's a constant `define`, which known as slower way to define a const since it defined at runtime. Its also applied for HTML, as people are always going to [minify it, but can't](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2359484/5816907)

Comment: Actually I can guests that short url is better but I want to learn that are there way to write images' urls without this way and with short urls?

Comment: I answered it indirectly on my post, if you can use the "normal" one, go for it. And for, _without this way and with short urls?_, it made me wanna ask a question: are you looking for a way to shorten the url? (this question is based of my last comment about "minifying HTML"). If you are, `.htaccess` can lead you to the right track. Even create [`symlink`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php) might do too.